# csv to dictionary in python (3.5.2)

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a csv that looks like this in excel:

```
1, Arborvitae
2, Japanese Maple
3, Dogwood
```

and so on.

I need a dictionary like this in python:

```
d = {1:'Arborvitae', 2:'Japanese Maple', 3:'Dogwood'}
```

Is there a way to do this? Without downloading modules off the internet. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv

with open('you_data.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    dic = dict(reader)
```

out:

```
{'3': ' Dogwood', '2': ' Japanese Maple', '1': ' Arborvitae'}
```

csv.reader read the csv file row by row, and contain each row's file in a list, something like

```
print(*reader)
['1', ' Arborvitae'] ['2', ' Japanese Maple'] ['3', ' Dogwood']
```

and reader is iterable, you can use `dict(iterable)` to construct a dict.
csv is standard library, so you donot need to download it.

Comment: Technically, the desired `dict` has `int` keys, so you couldn't use the `dict` constructor directly. You could do `dic = {int(k): v for k, v in reader}` though.

Comment: @ShadowRanger  thanks for the tip